# Is there a way to draw a horizontal line, across a whole page, no matter which context I'm in?

Tags: formatting

I've been using `\hline` for my horizontal lines in tabular, and `\line(1,0){250}` elsewhere.

I'm trying to automate some of the formatting for my tex documents, though, and it would be useful for me if I could draw a horizontal line across a page, no matter which context I'm in (whether I'm in tabular or not, for example). Is there a way to do this?

(I don't seem to be able to use \line, because of the width argument, so if there's a way to generate an appropriate number automatically there, that would work too)

Comment: Are you looking for this: [Alignment rules](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110801/10102)? Maybe not the same purpose, but [Gonzalo Medina's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110805/10102) enables to draw horizontal (and vertical) lines across a page.

Comment: yes, the answer includes an answer to my question

Comment: @blueberryfields can we then close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: yes, I think that makes sense