# Span background image across whole page

Tags: graphics, pdftex, backgrounds

I want to put a background image on a file which uses the *scrartcl* class. The target pdf output size is A4 which is exactly the size of the background image (210mm x 297mm). The image should therefore cover the whole page.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[allpages,picscale=1,picfile=./bg1,picfileext=png,picwidth=210mm,picheight=297mm,xpos=0,ypos=0]{}   
\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I get an error message

> Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line
>   11.  <./bg1.png, id=4, 597.432pt x 845.0772pt> File: ./bg1.png Graphic file (type png)
>
> Package pdftex.def Info: ./bg1.png used on input line
>   11. (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 597.50662pt x 845.0455pt.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \xwm@makedraftbox ...@begingroup
>   \ttfamily \color 
>                                                     {red}\Large (draft mode)\c... l.11 \end{document}

and the result does not look very promising

[image: screenshot]

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

This is the test-background I've used:

[image: background]

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115311/14757

Comment: Or better related: [Insert a full page image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the **background** package for this. Admittedly, this is mostly because I know it mostly works. (However, it turns out, there is also a good reason to use *something* other than **xwatermark** if using a KOMA class. See below.)

## Solution with **background** package

For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  contents={\includegraphics{bg1}},
  scale=1,
  angle=0
}
\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

[image: background background image]

## Diagnosis and solution with **xwatermark**

If you want to keep using **xwatermark**, things are a bit more complicated. The first point is that the package seems to require, but not load, the **color** package. At least, I got errors without it so I added

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

According to the manual (page 8):

> For graphics/picture watermarks, you need the `picfile` (the graphics
>   filename, with its full path but without its extension), `picfileext`
>   (the picture filename extension without the dot), `picbb` (the picture
>   bounding box), and `picscale` (the picture scale).

So I figured that I would see what happened if I set the watermark using just those keys. Not having much idea what the boundinb box should be, I took the default value **xwatermark** uses and made it explicit.

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[allpages,picscale=1,picfile=./bg1,picfileext=png,picbb=0 0 100 100]{}
```

This starts to give a sense of where the problem might lie:

[image: output with default bb and minimal settings]

Exactly the same result is obtained, unsurprisingly, if we use

```
\newwatermark[allpages,picscale=1,picfile=./bg1,picfileext=png,]{}
```

and let the package use the default bounding box.

So what is happening is that the package uses a bounding box which captures only a small part of the picture. Although `picscale=1` tells it not to scale the image, the later options setting the image's width and height override this and **xwatermark** scales the image accordingly. That is, it magnifies the small part of the picture inside the bounding box `0 0 100 100` so that it fills the requested area.

So, to get the desired output, it is necessary to determine the correct bounding box.

The output from running `pdflatex` tells us that the image dimensions are `597.432pt x 845.0772pt`. Hence, a good bet would seem to be

```
\newwatermark[allpages,picscale=1,picfile=./bg1,picfileext=png,picbb=0 0 597.432pt 845.0772pt]{}
```

and, indeed, this gives the desired result:

[image: output with corrected bounding box]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[allpages,picscale=1,picfile=./bg1,picfileext=png,picbb=0 0 597.432pt 845.0772pt]{}
\begin{document}
    Hello World!\newpage
    Bye-bye!
\end{document}
```

Note that use of **xwatermark** will break some functionality when using a KOMA class because the package loads **fancyhdr**. KOMA issues a warning about this on the console.

Unless you need **xwatermark** specifically, therefore, it would probably be better to use the **background** solution or similar. Not only is that strategy simpler, but it should also be fully compatible with KOMA as far as I know.