# Why is this picture moved to the left when using Minion?

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, grid-typesetting

This is a continuation from [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218971/how-to-align-baselines-of-picture-text-and-body-text), but the original issue there is (kind of) resolved.

For this question you need XeTeX, Minion Pro, which is shipped with Adobe Reader. `greybox.png` can be obtained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpXOh.png) and background grid is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41158/710).

The code is as follows:

```
\newbox\gridbox
\setbox\gridbox\line{%
  \special{color push rgb .8 .8 1}%
  \vrule height\baselineskip width0pt \hrulefill
  \special{color pop}}
\def\grid{\vtop to0pt{\hrule height0pt\kern-\dimexpr\baselineskip-\topskip\topskip=10pt\relax
    \vbox to\dimexpr\vsize+2pt\relax{\leaders\copy\gridbox\vfil}\vss}}
\def\pagebody{\vbox to\vsize{\boxmaxdepth=\maxdepth \grid\pagecontents}}

\parskip=0pt \frenchspacing \raggedbottom
\parindent=1pc

\font\rm="Minion Pro:+onum,+pnum:mapping=tex-text" at 10pt
\font\it="Minion Pro/I:+onum,+pnum:mapping=tex-text" at 10pt
\rm

\footline={\hfil\rm\folio\hfil}

\newcount\shapenum \newcount\tempnum \newcount\globpar
\newdimen\ii \newdimen\ww
\newdimen\picwidth  \newbox\picbox
\catcode`\@=11  
\def\oblom #1 from #2 indent #3 {\par \ii=#1 \ww=\hsize
   \ifdim\ii>\z@ \advance\ww by-\ii      
   \else \advance\ww by\ii \ii=\z@ \fi
   \shapenum=1 \tempnum=0 \def\shapelist{}
   \loop \ifnum\shapenum<#2 \edef\shapelist{\shapelist\z@\hsize}
      \advance\shapenum by1 \repeat
   \loop \edef\shapelist{\shapelist\ii\ww}
      \advance\tempnum by1 \ifnum\tempnum<#3 \repeat
   \advance\shapenum by#3 \edef\shapelist{\shapelist\z@\hsize}
   \doshape}  
\catcode`\@=12
\def\doshape{\globpar=0 \def\par{\ifhmode\shapepar\fi}}
\def\shapepar{\prevgraf=\globpar \parshape\shapenum\shapelist
   \endgraf \globpar=\prevgraf
   \ifnum \prevgraf>\shapenum \global\let\par=\endgraf \doshapeA \fi}

\ifx\XeTeXpicfile\undefined 
   \def\pic #1{\hbox{\pdfximage width\picwidth {#1}\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}}
\else
   \def\pic #1{\hbox{\XeTeXpicfile #1 width\picwidth}}
\fi

\def\\{\par}
\def\flowpic from #1 minus #2 width #3 #4#5{\par
   \dimen0=#3 \ifdim\dimen0<0pt \dimen0=-\dimen0 \fi
   %\advance\dimen0 by -1pc %(margin around picture)
   % create this margin differently: add margin to #3
   \dimen2=#3 \ifdim\dimen2<0pt \advance\dimen2 by -1pc
                          \else \advance\dimen2 by  1pc \fi
   \picwidth=\dimen0
   \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize\picwidth\pic{#4}%\kern .7mm 
                  \emergencystretch=2em \noindent\it #5\par}
   \dimen0=\ht0 
   \divide\dimen0 by\baselineskip \advance\dimen0 by1sp
   \advance\dimen0 by -#2sp
   \oblom \dimen2 from #1 indent \dimen0
   \advance\dimen0 by #2sp
   \multiply\dimen0  by\baselineskip
   \setbox\picbox=\vbox to\dimen0{\vss\box0}
   \dimen0=\pagegoal \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen \dimen0=\vsize\fi   
   \advance\dimen0 by-\pagetotal \advance\dimen0 by-#1\baselineskip
   \ifdim\dimen0<0pt 
      \def\doshapeA{\tempnum=\prevgraf \advance\tempnum by-#1 \advance\tempnum by2
         \line{\ifdim#3<0pt \hfill\fi \vbox to0pt{\vss\vtop to0pt{\kern0pt\box\picbox\vss}%
                   \kern\the\tempnum\baselineskip}\hfil}
         \nobreak\vskip-\baselineskip
      }
   \else \def\doshapeA{}
      \line{\ifdim#3<0pt \hfill\fi 
            \vtop to0pt{\kern-2\baselineskip\kern#1\baselineskip\box\picbox\vss}\hfil}
      \nobreak\vskip-\baselineskip
   \fi
}

\noindent
A work in progress, {\tt JSBox} is a self-contained
library---written in portable C---that instantiates sandbox-able,
\TeX-language interpreters within the memory space
of any C, Objective-C, or C++ 32- or 64-bit client
program. Built and documented anew, {\tt JSBox}
is faithful to the \TeX\ language's primitives,
syntax, typesetting algorithms, measurements, data
structures, and speed. At the same time, it fixes---in an
upwardly compatible manner---a variety of important
problems with or lacunæ in the current \TeX\ engine's
implementation. These include integral support for
21-bit Unicode, namespaces, OpenType font tables
and metrics, job-specific 8-bit to 21-bit Unicode
mapping, run-time settable compatibility levels,
full 32-bit fixed-point math, and more.
Especially pertinent to interactive applications---such as an
eBook reader---is that all of a document's pages can
optionally be kept as \TeX\ data structures in memory
after a job is done, with direct random access of any
requested page exported to the client program's screen
without file I/O or DVI or PDF conversion if unneeded.
Tracing (including recursive expansion, re-tracing
interrupted commands, alignments, math, etc.) and
all error messages have been significantly improved
over what \TeX\ does. The author will demo what
{\tt JSBox} can do now, and discuss what it
could do in the future.

A work in progress, {\tt JSBox} is a self-contained
library---written in portable C---that instantiates sandbox-able,
\TeX-language interpreters within the memory space
of any C, Objec\-tive-C, or C++ 32- or 64-bit client
program. Built and documented anew, {\tt JSBox}
is faithful to the \TeX\ language's primitives,
syntax, typesetting algorithms, measurements, data
structures, and speed. At the same time, it fixes
in an
upwardly compatible manner---a variety of important
problems with or lacunæ in the current \TeX\ engine's
implementation. These include integral support for
21-bit Unicode, namespaces, OpenType font tables
and metrics, job-specific 8-bit to 21-bit Unicode
mapping, run-time settable compatibility levels,
full 32-bit fixed-point math, and more. Especially
pertinent to interactive applications---such as an
eBook reader---is that all of a document's pages can
optionally be kept as \TeX\ data structures in memory
after a job is done, with direct random access of any
requested page exported to the client program's screen
without file I/O or DVI or PDF conversion if unneeded.
Tracing (including recursive expansion, re-tracing
interrupted commands, alignments, math, etc.) and
all error messages have been significantly improved
over what \TeX\ does. The author will demo what
{\tt JSBox} can do now, and discuss what it
could do in the future.

\flowpic from 11 minus 0 width -7cm {greybox.png}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
A work in progress, {\tt JSBox} is a self-contained
library---written in portable C---that instantiates sandbox-able,
\TeX-language interpreters within the memory space
of any C, Objective-C, or C++ 32- or 64-bit client
program. Built and documented anew, {\tt JSBox}
is faithful to the \TeX\ language's primitives,
syntax, typesetting algorithms, measurements, data
structures, and speed. At the same time, it fixes---in an
upwardly compatible manner---a variety of important
problems with or lacunæ in the current \TeX\ engine's
implementation. These include integral support for
21-bit Unicode, namespaces, OpenType font tables
and metrics, job-spe\-cific 8-bit to 21-bit Unicode
mapping, run-time settable compatibility levels,
full 32-bit\nobreak\ fixed-point math, and more.
Especially pertinent to interactive applications---such as an
eBook reader---is that all of a document's pages
can optionally be kept as \TeX\ data structures in memory
after a job is done, with direct random access of any
requested page exported to the client program's screen
without file I/O or DVI or PDF conversion if unneeded.
Tracing (including recursive expansion, re-tracing
interrupted commands, alignments, math, etc.) and
all error messages have been significantly improved
over what \TeX\ does. The author will demo what
{\tt JSBox} can do now, and discuss what it
could do in the future.

A work in progress, {\tt JSBox} is a self-contained
library---written in portable C---that instantiates sandbox-able,
\TeX-language interpreters within the memory space
of any C, Objective-C, or C++ 32- or 64-bit client
program. Built and documented anew, {\tt JSBox}
is faithful to the \TeX\ language's primitives,
syntax, typesetting algorithms, measurements, data
structures, and speed. At the same time, it fixes---in an
upwardly compatible manner---a variety of important
problems with or lacunæ in the current \TeX\ engine's
implementation. These include integral support for
21-bit Unicode, namespaces, OpenType font tables
and metrics, job-specific 8-bit to 21-bit Unicode
mapping, run-time settable compatibility levels,
full 32-bit fixed-point math, and more. 
These include integral support for
21-bit Unicode, namespaces, OpenType font tables
and metrics, job-specific 8-bit to 21-bit Unicode
mapping, run-time settable compatibility levels,
full 32-bit fixed-point\nobreak\ math, and more. These include integral support for
21-bit Unicode,{\parfillskip=0pt\par}
\flowpic from 1 minus 0 width -7cm {greybox.png}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\noindent namespaces, OpenType font tables
and metrics, job-specific 8-bit to 21-bit Unicode
mapping, run-time settable compatibilitylevels,
full 32-bit fixed-point math, and more. Especially
pertinent to interactive applications---such as an
eBook reader---is that all of a document's pages can
optionally be kept as \TeX\ data structures in memory
after a job is done, with direct random access of any
requested page exported to the client program's screen
without file I/O or DVI or PDF conversion if unneeded.
Tracing (including recursive expansion, re-tracing
interrupted commands, alignments, math, etc.) and
all error messages have been significantly improved
over what \TeX\ does. The author will demo what
{\tt JSBox} can do now, and discuss what it
could do in the future.

A work in progress, {\tt JSBox} is a self-contained
library---written in portable C---that instantiates sandbox-able,
\TeX-language interpreters within the memory space
of any C, Objective-C, or C++ 32- or 64-bit client
program. Built and documented anew, {\tt JSBox}
is faithful to the \TeX\ language's primitives,
syntax, typesetting algorithms, measurements, data
structures, and speed. At the same time, it fixes---in an
upwardly compatible manner---a variety of important %\nobreak\
problems with or lacunæ in the current \TeX\ engine's
implementation. These include integral support for
21-bit Unicode, namespaces, OpenType font tables
and metrics, job-specific 8-bit to 21-bit Unicode
mapping, run-time settable compatibility levels,
full 32-bit fixed-point math, and more. Especially
pertinent to interactive applications---such as an
eBook reader---is that all of a document's pages can
optionally be kept as \TeX\ data structures in memory
after a job is done, with direct random access of any
requested page exported to the client program's screen
without file I/O or DVI or PDF conversion if unneeded.
Tracing (including recursive expansion, re-tracing
interrupted commands, alignments, math, etc.) and
all error messages have been significantly improved
over what \TeX\ does. The author will demo what
{\tt JSBox} can do now, and discuss what it
could do in the future.
\bye
```

As you can see, the picture on page 2 is moved to the left:

[image: example image]

(also note the wider caption below the picture). The strange thing is that when I remove the (re)declaration of `\rm`, so cmr10 is used, the image isn't moved to the left (the use of Minion Italic in the caption apparently doesn't matter).

Why is this? Is this a bug in XeTeX?

Comment: It seems that there is a little bug in your modification of the macro `\flowpic`. The `\par` token at the end of the `\vbox` (`... \noindent\it #5\par}...`) is the source of the problem: this token is temporary redefined as a macro and it works as this (unwanted) macro when caption is formatted. Remove this token `\par`. The end of paragraph is processed at the end of `\vbox` without explicitly `\par` token, so it needn't to be here. Or replace the token `\par` by `\endgraf` here.

Comment: @wipet Indeed. But why doesn't it cause this issue when cmr10 is used? Anyway, post it as an answer and I'll happily mark it. BTW, I like your philosophy regarding TeX vs. LaTeX as described in your bio: I hate black boxes I don't understand and, in the worst case, conflict with eachother.

Comment: I have no Minion Pro font. I tried to modify your text with cmr10 in order to get the same problem. It was somewhat problematic because the line-break points are different and page-break depends on line-breaks due to `\brokenpenalty` register. But I was successful after little tests with cmr10 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core of the problem is the `\par` token at line 54 of your code:

```
   \setbox0=\vbox{\hsize\picwidth\pic{#4}%\kern .7mm 
                  \emergencystretch=2em \noindent\it #5\par}
```

The `\oblom` macro temporary redefines `\par` token in order to reset `\parshape` parameters for next paragraph if the indentation isn't finished. This is the reason why `\oblom` works in more than one paragraph. Note, that normal TeX `\par` removes `\parshape` settings definitely, so it cannot be used across more paragraphs without redefinition of `\par`.

So, the `\par` in your code at line 54 is expanded as a macro and this is the reason of broken typesetting. Solution: simply remove `\par` here, because the creating of paragraph is invoked at the end of `\vbox` automatically if horizontal mode is detected here. And this is an *exception* from another auto-`\par` processing: in TeX no `\par` token is inserted here (on the other hand `\par` token is inserted before `\vskip`, `\end`, etc. primitives by these primitives, pages 90--91 in *TeXbook naruby*).

You can object that the `\par` needn't to be redefined here because all indented lines from previous paragraphs were printed and the `\par` would be restored by

```
\ifnum \prevgraf>\shapenum \global\let\par=\endgraf \doshapeA \fi}
```

This is true, but there is a little bug in this code, because we need to say `\ifnum\prevgraf>=\shapenum...` which can be coded by:

```
\ifnum \prevgraf<\shapenum\else \global\let\par=\endgraf \doshapeA \fi}
```

I detected this bug in my code of the `\oblom` macro thanks your problem. Thank you, I'll correct this in the errata of *TeXbook naruby*.

Comment: You're welcome. And I noticed that I can get paragraphs within the caption text (parameter `#5`) when I do `\let\\=\par` outside of `\oblom` and then I can use `\\` inside the actual parameter without unwanted side-effects.

Comment: That `\\` should be two backslashes, of course, but the second one is eaten as an escape character in markdown.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Use `\let\\=\endgraf` instead `\let\\=\par`, because `\endgraf` is saved "original meaning" of `\par`.